# None Unicode library and windows locale

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, c++-cli, locale

I'm using(what seems to be) an ansi(or ascii??) dll library. I think it is such because the header file provided with the lib shows function using char*'s and LPSTR and LPCSTR and structs with char arrays.

This dll is loaded via ::LoadLibrary from a cpp/cli class library that wraps its functionality and exposes it to c#. A c# console app and various other class libs use this cli lib to perform operation.

I can make the cli assembly ether mutibyte or Unicode(which as far as I understand is the same in terms of language support) and c# apps are always Unicode.

This native dll is essentially a broker for a propriety back end server, it passes information back and froth from and to the server.

The issue I'm running into is that the native dll lib will only operate correctly for a particular language if the os locale, for none Unicode apps, its running in is set to that particular language.
I.e. if i want the app to correctly work with Chinese characters, that locale needs to be set. What I find hard to grasp is why does the locale matter for the broker. I understand that if the server is an ansi app if a user wanted to store none Unicode Chinese on it setting the locale on the server would make sense so it would in the client, but not in the middle man that just passes things along. Furthermore the whole thing is getting very confusing.

Is there away to pass Unicode to something like a char array in c++? Wold that even work in this scenario?

Here's a scenario I'm thinking about:

- c# app gets url encoded string
- c# app decodes the string and passes it to cli
- cli somehow converts the String^(or should it be byte[] at 
  this point) to char[] and passes it to the native lib

Should this really be possible? In terms of memory layout it should, i mean char is just a byte no?

Am I approaching this the right way? is there there a better way to accomplish cross language support. Mind you the vendor is on record saying that there is no way to mix languages in the api, but that's not what I'm looking for. I just dont want to have to run an instance of the software on a separate os for each language i want to support.

Comment: You can pass Unicode in a `char` array. You can encode the text using UTF-8 for example. However, that only works if the thing on the other end expects UTF-8. It would appear that the thing on the other end treats what it is sent as ANSI. In which case you have to send ANSI.

Comment: David, I'm pretty sure your right, both the broker lib and the back end are most likely ANSI, hence the vendor claiming that you cant mix languages. But the question remains, is the only way to support a language in this setup is with system wide locale config?

Comment: Pretty much. That's how it is with ANSI APIs. It's 2013, time you found a vendor that supports Unicode.

Comment: Touché. You made a statement though "In which case you have to send ANSI" is there any way for me to take in unicode, or something url encoded, line in the scenario I described above and produce ANSI character equivalent?

Comment: No because ANSI cannot encode the range of Unicode character points.

Comment: What about Encoding.Convert? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Well, it's possible to convert from any Unicode encoding to anything else. And of course you may well lose information in the conversion. But you've not really made it clear what this library does. You haven't said what you send it that makes it fail.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'Unicode' encoding.. Unicode has many different encodings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the approach described here:

[Is it possible to set ANSI encoding per application in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653176/is-it-possible-to-set-ansi-encoding-per-application-in-windows#comment20479699_14653176)

This is what worked for me

Answer (score 1):

What is confusing in this case, is that the DLL has a broken interface. Broken in the following sense: *it does not support all of the Unicode codepoints*. This is regardless of the type of parameters: char array is [perfectly good](http://www.utf8everywhere.org) for supporting all of unicode.

How do we know this? It is because, according to you, what it does depends on the system locale setting.

So, what to do? If the DLL source code is not under your control, you will not have it. You can, however, solve the problem of one ANSI codepage by setting the locale. It does not work for some languages.

Better would be to urge the DLL vendor to support unicode. Best encoding is, of course, UTF-8 - and this way it does not break existing code because the types LPCSTR remain the same.